# Access to the private key in Android ICS certificate storage

Tags: java, android, certificate, rsa

On Android ICS phone I have imported the PKCS#12 file containing private key and certificate.
Then i run

```java
KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this, this, new String[] { "RSA" }, null, null, -1, null);
```

In the certificate selection dialog i choose the one just installed.

In the 'alias' callback i do the following:

```java
public void alias(final String alias) {
...
protected Boolean[] doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
...
PrivateKey pk = KeyChain.getPrivateKey(ctx, alias);
Log.d(TAG, "EncodedPrivateKey: " + pk.toString());
```

And it gives me the full content of the private key.

Does it mean that any application, once allowed by user (in the cert. selection dialog), can read any private key installed from .pfx file?

Is the following scenario possible by standard Android means - "administrator" installing .pfx file with the cert.+private key and the permissions to read it are limited to the one specific app?

Comment: I believe you're right, if the user allows it then the key is basically useless. Don't know if its a bug or feature, seeing as how you might be able to override that dialog.